# Plesk-Scheduled-Tasks reporting "No such file or directory"

Tags: plesk

I have a working Centos/Plesk (18.0.40 Update #1) environment running Plesk-Scheduled-Tasks with no problems, and I have a new machine that should be a duplicate of that machine (Plesk 18.0.42 Update #1) that is failing to run the Plesk-Scheduled-Tasks (reporting "No such file or directory" on all the tasks that I have added).

Eliminating as many permissions factors as possible, I am testing a scriptless task running "whoami" will work on the original machine but shows an "-: whoami: command not found" error message on the new.

Note, I am also declaring tasks at the domain level - if I was to add a top level task (where it prompts you for the System user) then it can use root and therefore works - but I do not want these tasks to run under root.

[image]

Clicking "Run Now" gives the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hiho.

The run scheduled tasks and also the shell access if it´s enabled for your subscription is mostly chrooted. So you have only a minimum on commands which you can use here.

If you open your subscription via FTP Client you should see a bin folder in there. In the bin folder are all commands you are able to use in the chrooted shell.

Example on one of my subscriptions:

```
bash cat chmod cp curl du false grep groups gunzip gzip head id less ln ls
mkdir more mv pwd rm rmdir scp sh tail tar touch true unrar unzip vi wget
```